# Email Validation not working eventhough javascript is enabled and jquery validation working in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have an issue which is puzzling me. I have created a web page which on click of a button opens a bootstrap modal window which contains a form and for that form I used jquery validation. The strange part is I am getting some invalid email submissions like:

1. hgchjf kdf surb. j;e563@gamil .com
2. 991199
3. hcvjh CDs zm mnbv42768
4. Ali@hzhsbvxbs
5. ئؤؤللاااتتتن 7حع9ه7908غ7898خح8ح9هع9

Assuming javascript is not enabled, one cannot see the form itself so submission is out of question.

The jquery validation is working correctly and I have tested it with several different scenarios.
My validation script is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#contact-us-form").validate({
                      rules:{
                        emailAddress:{
                        minlength: 5,
                        maxlength: 255,
                        required: true,
                        validEmail: true
                        }
                      },
            ignore: '',

            highlight: function(element) {   

                $(element).addClass('error_new');    


                //HIGHLIGHT THE LABEL
                var textelement = "#"+($(element).attr("name"))+"_text";
                $(textelement).addClass('error_text');

                //HIGHLIGHT THE BORDER
                if($(element).siblings().length > 0){
                    var nextelement = $(element).siblings();
                    $(nextelement).css("border-color","#F00");  
                }

            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).removeClass('error_new');                                

                var textelement = "#"+($(element).attr("name"))+"_text";
                $(textelement).removeClass('error_text');

                if($(element).siblings().length > 0){                   
                    var nextelement = $(element).siblings();
                    $(nextelement).css("border-color","#CCC");  
                }                
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              if($(element).attr("name") == "emailAddress"){
                error.appendTo( element.parent("div") );
              }
            },
            messages: {
              emailAddress: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email adress",
                email: "Please enter a valid email adress"
              }
           }              
        }); 
      jQuery.validator.addMethod("validEmail", function(value, element) 
{    if(value == '') 
    return true;
var temp1;
temp1 = true;
var ind = value.indexOf('@');
var str2=value.substr(ind+1);
var str3=str2.substr(0,str2.indexOf('.'));
if(str3.lastIndexOf('-')==(str3.length-1)||(str3.indexOf('-')!=str3.lastIndexOf('-')))
    return false;
var str1=value.substr(0,ind);
if((str1.lastIndexOf('_')==(str1.length-1))||(str1.lastIndexOf('.')==(str1.length-1))||(str1.lastIndexOf('-')==(str1.length-1)))
    return false;
str = /(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\._-]{0,1})+([a-zA-Z0-9]+[_]{0,1})*@([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]{0,1})+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/;
temp1 = str.test(value);
return temp1;
}, "Please enter valid email.");
    });
</script>
```

I do not understand why am I getting invalid email submissions. Any ideas on this issue will be a lot helpful.

Comment: You should always do server-side validation.

Comment: @ gcampbell: I have learnt from my mistake and I am doing that now, but I want to know the reason why this is happening?